# Only use certain fields from json in nuxt app

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

By using asyncdata and axios I am grabbing a json object from a database called Knack.

Working great however the whole response is huge and in some pages I’m only using say 10 fields from sometimes 50+.

So I’m grabbing records from knack and then using v-for to loop through and output 10 of the 50+ fields from say 200 records.

By looking in console I can see the whole json object.

Is there a way to get the json object as I am and rather than returning it all, loop through and create a smaller object with the fields I need and returning that to then do a v-for in my template? Basically resulting in only the required fields being visible in console and to the public?

Thanks so much if someone can help with a code sample.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way.

**Sample data model**

```
 data() {
  return {
    // Required fields to filter data
    requiredFields: ["name", "phone", "email"],
    fields: {
      name: "Wade Mckenzie",
      phone: "1-278-483-8300",
      email: "ac.mattis.velit@magnisdisparturient.net",
      address: "971-2324 Id, Av.",
      list: 7,
      country: "Australia",
      postalZip: "422625",
      region: "Campania",
      text: "malesuada augue ut lacus. Nulla tincidunt, neque vitae semper egestas,",
      numberrange: 5,
      currency: "$9.91",
      alphanumeric: "TXQ00DEL5RP",
   },
  };
 }
```

**Computed prop**

```
computed: {
  filteredData() {

    // Create an empty object
    let requiredData = {};

    // Loop over the entries
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.data)) {

      // Check if the property is a required field
      if (this.requiredFields.includes(key)) {
        requiredData[key] = value;
      }
    }
 
   return requiredData;
  },
}
```

**Template**

```
<div v-for="(value, name) in filteredData" :key="name">
  {{ name }}: {{ value }}
</div>
```

You can check out the [working example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/v-for-display-required-fields-rwe8d?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Thanks so much @catagec I really appreciate the detailed reply. I'm using asyncdata was it possible to show me how you would use it with your code? Example from https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching/#async-data

```export default {
    async asyncData({ params, $http }) {
      const post = await $http.$get(`https://api.nuxtjs.dev/posts/${params.id}`)
      return { post }
    }
  }```

Comment: Sure. You can see how I did it with asyncData by checking [this example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/filtered-asyncdata-424ki?file=/pages/index.vue).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in a computed property.

```
computed(){
    getCustomObject(){

        let customObject = {};
        for(let property in yourJsonObject){
            if(property == 'the field you want'){
                customObject[`${property}`] = yourJsonObject[property]
            }
        }
        
        return customObject;
    }
}
```

In this way you can get specific fields that you want. But you will have to specify them by placing `||` in the `if` statement.

In template you can simply render it like this: -

```
<div v-for="(item,key,index) in getCustomObject" :key="index">
    //Render data...
</div>
```

Or if you just want a specific number of fields like 10 fields from 50, you can do it like this: -

```
computed(){
    getCustomObject(){

        let customObject = {};
        Object.entries(yourJsonObject).forEach(([key,value],index) => {
            if(index<10){
              customObject[`${key}`] = value;
            }
        })
        
        return customObject;
    }
}
```